# I recently intalled ubuntu and I am a biginner for Linux...I am unable to execute commands in ubuntu 20.4. Pls help me

Tags: python-3.x

Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

command 'python3' from deb python3
command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

Comment: check https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144446/python-installed-in-ubuntu-but-python-command-not-found and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296790/python-is-python3-package-in-ubuntu-20-04-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt-get is your friend! Try to install it first.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

To verify it's installed:

```
python3 --version
```

If something goes wrong, try to google it like: "linux install python"

Hope it helps. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you so much for u r answer. It solved my problem...